# Delete image from android gallery captured after particular date/time

Tags: android, image-gallery

I am working on a project where I need to take multiple images from camera. I am looking for a way where I can delete images from gallery which are taken after particular date/time.

Please advice

Comment: use `File` class to check if picture exists and remove etc , another advice try your self first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to query the [MediaStore.Images](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html)...something like this:

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " < ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(YOUR_DATE_MILLIS) };
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
    .query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
        projection, 
        selection, 
        selectionArgs, 
        null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext() {
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(0);
    }
}

cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure which will be launched with your application, checking all the files of a particular folder, and deleting the images from a certain period.